# When using gem 'aws-sdk-core' with active record facing issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, rubygems, aws-sdk

I have installed the gem 'aws-sdk-core' and in my model I have define

```
class abcd < Aws::Record::Base
  ab = Pathname.new("#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml")
  cd = YAML::load(ERB.new(File.read(path)).result)

  set_domain_name cd[Rails.env]['domain']      
end
```

I am using this aws for running my rake tasks.so when am running my rake task its giving error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Aws::Record
/home/project/app/models/abcd.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Please help me in finding the solution. Thank's in advance!!!

Comment: how did you install `aws-sdk-core`? Its most likely that your gem is not included to your rails. Best practice it place it in your Gemfile and `bundle install`.

Comment: I had added it my gem file ' gem 'aws-sdk-core' ' and done bundle install

Answer (score 0):

The v2 AWS SDK for Ruby does not included the `AWS::Record` abstraction from v1. You can continue using the v1 implementation for now, as both v1 and v2 gems can be used in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i just ran into this issue and resolved. It is because AWS updated their gem to 2.0. If you update the gem to 2.0 different configuration is required.

If you want to using the version you had before, just change the Gemfile like below:

Gemfile

gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'